# Bootstrap Menu Dropwon <li> goes to the right

Tags: php, html, css

So i want the list of the dropdown to be in the same line I don't know why it goes to the right

Bug Drop Down

[image]

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Mensagens</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Suporte</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='corpo.php?option=LOGOFF'>Logoff</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use a <br> =D
Oly joking,you must style those <li> to be vertical list, Inspect dropdown li  elements, there have to be something that rewrite your dropdown <li> styles.

I reccomend you trying to force those <li> to be displayed as blocks.
ul.dropdown-menu > li{display:block;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its with CSS of the anchor tags in the list item of dropdown menu.

It is set it the following by default:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  padding: 3px 20px;
}
```

If you change the padding to 12px , it directly aligns with the dropdown button text.

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  padding: 3px 12px;
}

.dropdown-menu{
 min-width:120px;
 }
```

That is same as the default padding for the btn class. 
This should fix the shift. 
Also changing min-width property as your list items are declared to be inline.

Comment: All i did was add dropdown class around your code, everything else is pretty much the same.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pgLsujte/1/ See now, i cant put everything so it doenst show up really well but i update it and gets to the other side see if something is wrong, its a mess btw

Comment: Umm... i see it now, you had list items as inline, so the min-width property for dropdown menu class is giving enough width for your options to stack up to the right.
you can change it by reducing the min-width property, 
    .dropdown-menu{
     min-width:120px;
     }
I have re-edited the answer to add this code.

Comment: I copied and still the same :\ , im so confused I hate CSS i dont know what to do

Comment: By the way , i tried now and if i put another Li in the middle of Logoff and Suport like a letter 'L' , logoff goes to the right place 
Ex: https://gyazo.com/0c139af1ae0ba5aaa327518fac222bb1
Its weird

Comment: here is the link, your code i have commented what i have done 
https://jsfiddle.net/saa93/enenewcd/2/

Comment: oh , im so sorry i didnt saw the comment on removing the 200px :| im dumb xd Thank you very much it worked, i was having a struggle with this , i prefer php and sql :P

Answer (score 1):

***....Try this....***

For css:

```
.dropdown{
float: right;
} 
.btn{
background-color: #2952a3;
 color: white;
}
```

For HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Mensagens</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Suporte</a> 
            <a href='corpo.php?option=LOGOFF'>Logoff</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div></div>
```